# json data returned from wcf service incomplete

Tags: c#, json, wcf

I'm returning JSON from a NET class with 4 properties from my WCF service.  The problem is when it gets sent to the browser (IE, Chrome, FF).  it only returns one of the properties from the class

.NET class:

```
[DataContract]
    public class MASInspections
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int MaintID { get; set; }
        public string MHID { get; set; }
        public DateTime MaintDate { get; set; }
        public string pdfReport { get; set; }

    }
```

.NET Interface:

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        UriTemplate = "GetInspectionByReach/{Reach}")]
    List<MASInspections> GetInspectionByReach(string Reach);
```

.NET Method:

```
 public List<MASInspections> GetInspectionByReach(string Reach)
    {
        List<MASInspections> InspInfos = new List<MASInspections>();
        DataSet ds = DBCalls.GetInspectionByReach(Reach);
        DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
        DataRowCollection drc = dt.Rows;
        for (int i = 0; i < drc.Count; i++)
        {
            object[] values = drc[i].ItemArray;
            MASInspections InspInfo = new MASInspections();
            InspInfo.MaintID = Convert.ToInt32(values[0]);
            InspInfo.MHID = Convert.ToString(values[1]);
            InspInfo.MaintDate = Convert.ToDateTime(values[5]);
            InspInfo.pdfReport = Convert.ToString(values[6]);
            InspInfos.Add(InspInfo);
        }

        return InspInfos;//this inlcudes all 4 properties
    }
```

when the json gets sent to the browser, only the MaintID is there:

```
    {"GetInspectionByReachResult":[{"MaintID":133},{"MaintID":178}]}
```

Any ideas why this would be?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is your problem:

```
[DataContract]
    public class MASInspections
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int MaintID { get; set; }
        public string MHID { get; set; }
        public DateTime MaintDate { get; set; }
        public string pdfReport { get; set; }

    }
```

you need:

```
[DataContract]
    public class MASInspections
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int MaintID { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string MHID { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public DateTime MaintDate { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string pdfReport { get; set; }

    }
```